# Issue with format specification while reading from file Matlab

Tags: matlab, formatting, format, printf, scanf

I have a .dat file with a table containing data in following order:

```
0,000E+0   4,069E-2  -5,954E+0   1,851E-2
```

What I need to do is to read this data with matlab and then somehow handle it.
Here is my code:

```
path = 'C:/Users/user/Desktop/file1.dat';
fileID = fopen(path,'r');
formatSpec = '%e';
A = fscanf(fileID,formatSpec);
fclose(fileID);
disp(A);
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Please clarify what "doesn't work" means. Do you get an error? If so post the text, or provide some more detail about what happens.

Comment: After disp() i get an empty array with no data, so this is what i want to fix

Comment: you have comma in data? You should replace it with dot.

Comment: I have avout 1000 numbers, how do i replace it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After replacement of comma with dot in data you can read it using `dlmread` function:

```
M = dlmread('filename', '   ');
```

`M` is what you want.
For the first part, replacing a character, you can use the following code:

```
% read the file
fid  = fopen('input.txt','r');
f=fread(fid,'*char')';
fclose(fid);

%replace the char
f = strrep(f,',','.');

% write into the another file    
fid  = fopen('output.txt','w');
fprintf(fid,'%s',f);
fclose(fid);
```

Comment: I cant replace comma manually, there are to many numbers in table

Comment: @PetukhovLive replace it by a text editor likes notepad++. using Replace All, not by hand.

Comment: @PetukhovLive my answer is updated to support your case for replacing.